# Create calendar view with powershell, set Day View Sub Heading value

Tags: 2013, sharepoint-enterprise, powershell, calendar

I am trying to create a SharePoint calendar view with powershell. I need to be able to set the "Day View Sub Heading" value but can't find the fieldref for this type. This is what I have so far (and works):

```
$viewData="<FieldRef Name='StatusTitle' Type='CalendarMonthTitle'/><FieldRef Name='Title' Type='CalendarWeekTitle'/><FieldRef Name='Location' Type='CalendarWeekLocation' /><FieldRef Name='Title' Type='CalendarDayTitle' /><FieldRef Name='Location' Type='CalendarDayLocation' />";
```

I was looking for something along the lines of:

```
<FieldRef Name='Session' Type='CalendarDaySubHeading' />
```

Answer (score 0):

I was mistaken. The Day View Sub Heading type is named CalendarDayLocation. The reason I was thrown for a loop here is because someone change the title of calendar's "Location" column to another value.